# copy and resize an image to folder A if the image does not exist in the folder B

Tags: python, file

I have 800000 images in folderA. I am resizing and copying the image from one folder to another. I lost connectivity in the middle so the process stop midway. Now I am trying to first check if the file exists in folder B or not and if it does not exist then resize and copy to folder B from A. I am trying using os.path.file but the code is not working.  This is what I have tried

```
import os
path1 = "/home/folderA/"
path2 = "/home/folderB/"
new_list = os.listdir(path1)
train_list = list(new_list)
for i in train_list: 
    if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path1, 'i')) and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path2, 'i')):
        img = cv2.imread(path + i,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        img = cv2.resize(img,(256,256))
        cv2.imwrite(path2 + i,img)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the conditional to `if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path2, i))':`.

Also use `os.path.join(path2, i)` and not `os.path.join(path2, 'i')`, and change `path + i` to `os.path.join(path, i)`, likewise for `path2`.